# How is Disk Usage Determined?

Tags: macos, storage

When I open my internal hard drive, which is also my start-up disk, **Finder** lists my account (I’m only user) as taking up 123 GB.

I double-click on my Home folder and sort items by size. Adding all folders containing over 100 MB, I only get about 22 GB. That leaves about 1 GB’s worth of files.

Where are the missing 100 GB?

I ran `df -h` under my Home folder, which shows about 101 GiB occupied. However most of that is taken up by the `Library`. What is this folder and why is it so large (93 GiB)?

I also ran Daisy Disk to map my drive. In addition to the 92 GB in the Library folder, it reports that iCloud Drive is using 55 GB and that a section it denotes as 'hidden spaces' is using 80 GB. Why does the iCloud Drive use 55 GB on my disk and what could 'hidden spaces' possibly be?

Answer (score 1):

The ~/Library folder is where the system stores different things(settings for apps, steam games, iOS backups, downloads of iOS apps from iTunes and etc.)

You can look at the folder by going to your home folder in Finder, press Command(⌘)+ j and check the box that says "Show Library folder"

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Daisy Disk](https://daisydiskapp.com/). It will give you a great visual representation of what’s taking space on your drive, and how much.

Comment: I already know 92 GB are in the .Library directory. I'm trying to figure out what this directory is.

Comment: I ran Daisy Disk. It showed that Library took up 92 GB.

Comment: You added that `.` back, but I have no idea what the `.Library` folder is, as it is not standard. Why don’t you open it and look inside? The normal `Library` folder contains almost everything that pertains to your user account: caches, preferences… Most of the space taken up by that folder on my system is iOS device backups.

Comment: Again, you can open that folder with DaisyDisk and look inside.

Comment: yes your right about the Library directory. But Daisy Disk also says that iCloud Drive is using 57 GB and that 'hidden space' uses 80 GB.  Why is my iCloud Drive taking up disk space and what is 'hidden space'?  Daisy Disk says 'hidden space' is probably other users accounts except there are no other users.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I removed the . I guess they are the same. du listed it as .Library.  Daisy Disk listed it as Library.

Comment: .Library is the standard name of the ~/library folder, but it gets renamed from .library to library when you set it not to be hidden in Finder

Comment: @Harcker ~/.Library is **not** the name of the ~/Library folder before unhiding it! It's a simple *hidden* flag (an attribute in the HFS+ file system) which gets changed to make this folder visible! Same with /private and other folders and soft links in the root folder.

Comment: Hidden space can be usually revealed in DaisyDisk using its command "Scan as Administrator". If it doesn't help, it may be a file system problem, then use Disk Utility's "First Aid" button, then rescan in DaisyDisk. That usually fixes the problem of hidden space.